# Alternating sum of a part of a row of Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^m(-1)^r{n \choose r}=(-1)^m{n-1 \choose m}$ if $m$ is less than $n$.

This question actually consists of two part that is when $m$ is less than $n$ and when $m$ is equal to $n$. I can solve the second part but not the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use induction on $m$. This boils down to proving
$$ (-1)^m \binom{n-1}{m} + (-1)^{m+1} \binom{n}{m+1} = (-1)^{m+1} \binom{n-1}{m+1}, $$
which follows from Pascal's identity.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\pars{-1}^{r}{n \choose r}
     =\pars{-1}^{m}{n - 1 \choose m}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\pars{-1}^{r}{n \choose r}}
> =\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\pars{-1}^{r}\ \overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{r + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ {n \choose r}}}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{r}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}{\pars{-1/z}^{m + 1} - 1 \over -1/z - 1}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}\,{z^{m + 1} + \pars{-1}^{m} \over z^{m}\pars{1 + z}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\ \underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\
> \pars{-1}^{m}\
> \underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{m + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{=\ {n - 1 \choose m}}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\pars{-1}^{r}{n \choose r}
=\pars{-1}^{m}{n - 1 \choose m}}
$$